# Import module (without Gradle) to my Android Gradle project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with Gradle and I want import an android module to my project. The problem is that this module has not Gradle. Is it possible import with build.gradle this module?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

If you can compile your module into its own JAR then you can add it as a Gradle dependency using something like:

```
repositories {
  flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'myjar:1.0@jar'
}
```

or

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

or

```
dependencies {
  compile files('libs/my-jar.jar')
}
```

Comment: And if you cant compile it into a JAR??

Comment: In what way are you trying to include it in your Gradle project? At some point your code will need to be compiled into an artifact (APK or AAR) and for Gradle to do that with the module you want to include, the module either needs to be packaged into an artifact already (JAR) or it needs to be a part of the Gradle project. What is the reason you don't want to include it as a Gradle module?

Comment: I add some modules like this: compile project(":MyModule") but one of these has not Gradle.  it is a third module that does not allow us to compile as a jar.

Comment: I think you should go ahead and add the module to the Gradle project. Even if it doesn't have any Java code that will compile into a JAR, any resources in that module can still be packaged into the final artifact or into a different artifact like a TAR. Could you please provide the reason for not wanting to add this as a Gradle module or maybe some more details on what is in this module that is needed by the rest of the Gradle project?

Comment: Yes, I want include the module into the Gradle project. I`ll try to compile into a Jar and add to the project. There is no way to include the module without compile it into a jar?

Comment: The module is compiled with Maven and there are some resources like drawables, this is the reason beacause I cant compile into a JAR.

Comment: Oh I see... instead of a JAR, you can configure that project as an Android library to package it as an AAR. This would still mean that you need to build that module with Gradle. I suggest that you ditch Maven and convert the POM over to a build.gradle. I've done it before and it really is pretty simple.